# How to install numpy in OSX properly?

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I'm using the built in python version in OSX, I also installed pip by `sudo easy_install pip` and secondly I installed numpy by `sudo pip install numpy`.

However, when I run any python file which uses numpy I get an error message like:

> > `Import error: No module named numpy`

Like numpy isn't installed in system. When I called `locate numpy` I found out most of outputs tell numpy is installed at: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/Python/numpy`

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the built-in python for OS X is not recommended and will likely cause more headaches in the future (assuming it's not behind your current problems).

Assuming your python is fine, there's still the issue of getting numpy working. In my experience, installing numpy with pip will often run into problems.

In addition to CT Zhu's advice, if you just want numpy and python, the Enthought distribution is quite good and free for students.

Also getting Homebrew working is a good idea and, because it's quite well supported, is not hard. With homebrew, installing numpy is as easy as `brew install numpy` -- and it makes installing other packages that also often don't install right with pip (sklearn, scipy, etc) easy too.

Comment: The "light" Enthought distribution (now rebranded under Canopy if I'm not mistaken) includes numpy/scipy and I have had good luck installing that. Doing a complete Enthought / Canopy install does leave you with the problem that Apache still uses the 'old' Python installation - so if you are using your Mac as a web server and want active pages with python for graphs, you're still out of luck. I did once solve that problem - unfortunately I didn't keep good notes but it was quite a headache (and involved recompiling some modules - `wsgi` if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

Did `sudo pip install numpy` actually succeed?

Either way, you can download a binary package for OSX from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.0/).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the buildin python that shipped with OSX, did you install other python?

Anyway, besides what @Claudiu mendtioned, you can get a 'distribution':

Canopy [Here](https://www.enthought.com/downloads/) or Anaconda [Here](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/).

Or use macport:

Guide [Here](http://sublimated.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/how-to-install-matplotlib-and-scipy-using-macports/)